# DataGridView ComboBoxCell is not showing values that are not from the list vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridcomboboxcolumn

Hi all i have  a combobox which is nicely populated from a binding source. So the problem is the column of the datagrid "Name" is only showing values which comes from the populated drop down list. Those values that is not the same as the droplist is shown empty. can someone tell me why? below is they code for the combobox. I cant printscreen but the describtion is like this. The LIst has 3 names : John , Jake, Jay but the colum has over 10 name , each in its respective cell. The problem when onload it is not showing the other names.

```
    Dim c4 As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()

    c4.HeaderText = "Name"
    c4.Name = "Name"
    c4.DataPropertyName = "Name"
    c4.DisplayMember = "NamesWithJ"
    c4.ValueMember = "NamesWithJ"
    c4.DisplayStyleForCurrentCellOnly = False
    c4.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing
    c4.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard
    c4.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic
    c4.DataSource = AddtBndSrc
    c4.Width = 100
    Me.DataGrid.Columns.Add(c4)
```

And here is the code where i create the bindingsource and fill it with value. There is no error with the connection its showing perfectly. It just that the comboboxcolumn is showing null in some of the rows

```
                   Try

       con = New SqlConnection(strConnection)

      cib.Open()

        adoAAda = New SqlDataAdapter(StrAddNameQuery, con)

        adoAddtRs = New DataSet



        adoAAda.Fill(adoAddtRs)

        Dim tableAddt As DataTable = adoAddtRs.Tables(0)

        Dim colum As DataColumn = tableAddt.Columns(0)


        tableAddt.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {tableAddt.Columns(0)}

        AddtBndSrc.DataSource = adoAddtRs.Tables(0)


        con.close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Try
        ' connection procedure
     con = New SqlConnection(strConnection)

       con.Open()

        adoPAda = New SqlDataAdapter(StrProductQuery, con)

        adoProductsRS = New DataSet



        adoPAda.Fill(adoProductsRS)

        Dim tableProduct As DataTable = adoProductsRS.Tables(0)

        Dim colum As DataColumn = tableProduct.Columns(0)


        tableProduct.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {tableProduct.Columns(0)}

        productBndSrc.DataSource = adoProductsRS.Tables(0)

        MsgBox(tableProduct.Columns(0).ColumnName.ToString)
       con.close

        datagridview.Datasource = productBndSrc

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: Can you share all code for DataGridViewdata datasource and the way it is bound?

Comment: hmmmm i dont know how to say this but they are 7 columns each are manually generated. So the coding above is repeated. So would you want that or the way i fill the dataset and binding source??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to merge values for combobox. Some are hardcoded into combo but are pulled from database. If so, you need to added the hardcoded values into datasource before binding to combo.

after following lines ADD THE CODE GIVEN BELOW.

```
    adoAAda.Fill(adoAddtRs)
    Dim tableAddt As DataTable = adoAddtRs.Tables(0)
```

'ADD YOUR HARD CODED NAMES TO DATASOURCE BEFORE BINDING

```
    Dim tableAddt As DataTable = adoAddtRs.Tables(0)

    Dim dr As DataRow = tableAddt.NewRow
    dr("NamesWithJ") = "My test 1"
    tableAddt.Rows.Add(dr)
    Dim dr1 As DataRow = tableAddt.NewRow
    dr("NamesWithJ") = "My test 2"
    tableAddt.Rows.Add(dr1)
```

Comment: ITs not what i am looking for but it gave me an idea. Create a second query which is from the table being displayed in the gridview and add it to the combobox column's table. Then use linq to select distinct or something like that. thanks for the idea man

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are assigning the combobox bindingSource `AddtBndSrc` to the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` datasource. So if that colum had some items assigned they will be overwritten by the datasource.

Comment: Well is there any ways to fixed this i was using the jay john and jake as an example. It actually from of a product name being listed in an order table. How ever the table which is the datasource of the gridview has new product names which the list does not have. But i dont really have rights to go in and change the table which holds the product names and IDs inside the database(i am scared i might screw up) . So i am stuck here any solutions

Comment: I dont know if I am understanding you. Buy try removing preassigned values to the Gridview column, and just use the same binding source for the combobox and the grid column

Comment: But what if the possibility that they are over 10 products but only 5 rows it means the list would be limited to 5 instead of the 10 products. So i guess the main problem is the datagridview comboboboxcell only shows values if they are similar to the list. How to fix this problem??